# Query from DB Azure to Local Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have this situation.

I have 2 BD , one DB in Azure with Name: TEST1 and another in my computer with name Test2.

I want to execute querys in BD Test1 to consult information in DB Test2.

How can i do this?

Regards.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to setup a linked server where an Azure DB can query a local DB?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure does not support linked servers.  (SQL Azure Managed Instance does for SQL-SQL connections, FWIW).

Absent that, your options are:
* run SQL Server on your local machine and run the query from there to join (using a linked server to talk to SQL Azure's db)
* run SQL Server in a VM in azure to do linked servers there against your two databases.

- SQL Server 2019 CTPs do contain an external table feature that is able to talk to ODBC sources like SQL Server/SQL Azure, but that's not materially any different than the two options I suggested for you here.  (It's a bit more involved to do this path and it's not supported for production workloads at this time since it's pre-RTM).